# C program, Multiple Child and pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I have to develop a mini card game (Go Fish) on C language which have the following requirements.
1. players of 2-8 child.
2. every child have to communicate with the parent through two dimensional pipe.

My progress now is that I have already finished the child creation and the setting of two dimensional pipes for every child, however, when I start doing the dealing card process, some problems come out and I tried so long to figure it out. Unlucky, I fail lots of times and I would like to ask here.

Question 1: During the dealing process, parent will deal 7 cards to child and the every child needs to receive these cards and save into their own deck(which is a string array). However, my output shows that the string array becomes 7 equals cards which is not expected.

[Output :All equal cards in the deck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e3Dx.png)

Question 2: How can I have a dynamic string array to store the cards information. Since during the game, every players may have a chance of having more then 7 cards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int seed;

void initrand(int myid){
    seed = myid;
}

int myrand(){
    return (seed++ % 99)+1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pid, myid ,parentid, cid, seed, who, rank, cpp;//cpp = card per person
    //Total number of argument
    int num_arg = (argc-1);
    int i,j,TotalchildNo,RemainchildNo,childNo;

    //The total number of child process
    TotalchildNo = RemainchildNo = atoi(argv[1]);

    //<Pipes>
    int parent_to_child[2*TotalchildNo];
    int child_to_parent[2*TotalchildNo];
    //</Pipes>

    char writebuf[80], readbuf[80];

    //For 2-4 players
    if(TotalchildNo>=2||TotalchildNo<=4) cpp=7;
    //For 4-8 players
    else if (TotalchildNo>=4||TotalchildNo<=8) cpp=5;

    //Creating Pipe
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalchildNo; i++) {
        pipe(&parent_to_child[2*i]);
        pipe(&child_to_parent[2*i]);
    }

    //Creating child
    for(i=0;i<TotalchildNo;i++){
        childNo = i;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid){
            continue;
        } else if (pid==0){
            break;
        } else {
            printf("fork error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    if(pid==0){ //Child process
        //printf("%d Child: %d\n",getpid(),childNo);
        //Pipe setup
        close(parent_to_child[2*childNo+1]);
        close(child_to_parent[2*childNo]);

        char *cards[30];
        int numOfCards=0;
        const char s[2] = " ";

        for(i=0;i<cpp;i++){
            //printf("Child %d listening to parent.\n",childNo);
            read(parent_to_child[2*childNo],readbuf,80);
            cards[i]=readbuf;
            printf("Card %d: %s %s\n",i+1,readbuf, cards[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n",cards[0],cards[1],cards[2],cards[3],cards[4],cards[5],cards[6]);


        //exit(0);
    }else 

    {// Parent process
        //Pipe setup (Close for every child invalid pipe)
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalchildNo; i++) {
            close(parent_to_child[2*i]);
            close(child_to_parent[2*i+1]);
        }
        //Initialize the deck of the parent
        char card[4];

        //Dealt card according to numbers of the players
        for(i=0;i<cpp;i++){
            for(j=0;j<TotalchildNo;j++){
                //Send on card to specific player
                fgets(card, sizeof card , stdin);
                strcpy(writebuf,card);
                write(parent_to_child[2*j+1],writebuf,80);              
            }
        }


        while(RemainchildNo>0){
            cid = wait(NULL);
            printf("Child %d has returned!\n",RemainchildNo);
            --RemainchildNo;
        }
    }

}
```

English is not my native language, I feel very sorry if you think my explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: `cards[i]=readbuf;` - think *hard* about what that line of code actually does. What type of array is `cards` ? At every `card` slot you're storing the same *value* : the address of your read buffer, the content of which is overwritten with each read operation. Consequently all cards appear to not only be the same card, they're also the *last* card received. You need to make copies of those strings and store those addresses instead.

Comment: cards[i]=readbuf;  The purpose of this code is to store the string value inside the pipe reading buffer. The type of the "cards" I expected is the string array which storing all the cards of the child

Comment: Can I say that : for now, all my value inside cards is pointing to the readbuf addresses therefore, all of the cards information is same with the latest information about readbuf?

Comment: Your latter comment is nearly verbatim to what I described. All that line of code does is save the base address of the read buffer into a slot in a pointer array (an array of pointers). When done, all slots in the pointer array have the same address, and therefore all will *appear* to have the same card. In reality, they *do* have the same card, but not because there are N distinct copies. Rather because they are actually pointing to the same memory location. In short, they not only "have" the same card, they **are** the same card, right down to the memory they occupy.

Comment: I got you point! But how can I resolve this problem? I know I have to create the copy of the value inside the readbuf however, how...

Comment: By making copies of the strings; again, exactly as I said in my last sentence of my first comment. If you're writing pipe code in C, you had better already know how to make a copy of a string in C. The latter is one of the things you learn in week-one of an C programming class.